# ?= vs ||= in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, operators

I am trying to pick a reliable operator for "if variable is not defined or initialize, then declare and initialize".

Consider an example (the semantics is not really important):

```
window.test ?= 123

location.origin ||= location.protocol + "//" + location.host
```

This gets translated into the following Javascript:

```
var _ref;

if ((_ref = window.test) == null) {
  window.test = 123;
}

location.origin || (location.origin = location.protocol + "//" + location.host);
```

Which is a better way to do this? It appears to me that the `||=` operator is more reliable because it also accounts for "undefined" But why does CoffeeScript promote the use of `?=` instead? Am I missing something?

Comment: Keep in mind `undefined == null` evaluates to `true` due to type coercion so `?=` handles the `undefined` case as well.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript, `undefined == null`<sup>1</sup>, so it does account for `undefined`. `||=` is usually undesirable because it will overwrite any falsy value even when it's not `null` or `undefined`, e.g., zero or false.

<sup>1</sup>In JavaScript, `==` sometimes implicitly coerces values, and one of those cases is `null` and `undefined`. (See items 2 and 3 of [section 11.9.3 in the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `undefined == null`. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, if so could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to pick a reliable operator for "if variable is not defined or initialize, then declare and initialize".

It is impossible to conditionally declare a variable in a host that is compliant with ECMA-262. It is possible to test for the presence of global variables since they are made properties of the global (window) object (but it won't tell you if they were created as global variables or properties). To test for a global:

```
// In global scope:
var global = this;

// Wherever:
if (global.hasOwnProperty('foo')) { // throws an error in IE
  // foo is a property of the global object
}
```

It is impossible to test for a local variable (say within a function) since you can't access the variable object or execution context object to test it, all you can do is test against `undefined` or use `try..catch` (ugly). But needing to do that is very poor design.

If the intention is to conditionally create a property of the global object, then the above leads to:

```
if (!global.hasOwnProperty('foo')) { // throws an error in IE
  global.foo = 'whatever';
}
```

However, if you also want to test if the property has been assigned a value, then:

```
if (typeof global.foo == 'undefined') { // works everywhere
```

Seems more appropriate as if the above returns true, then either it hasn't been declared, hasn't been assigned a value, or has been assigned a value of `undefined`. In all cases, you probably want to now assign a value.

Testing against `null` does not seem sensible, since the only way it will have that value is if it was explicitly assigned (which means the property exists and has been assigned a value).

Comment: Using `typeof` would be nicer of course, but this isn't just any JavaScript ... it's CoffeeScript :)

Comment: Indeed, but isn't it possible to use `typeof` rather than the CoffeeScript operators?

Comment: Surely it's possible, it's just that they promote the `?=` operator for cases like these; don't ask me why :)

Comment: @Jack It's because the variants of the existential operator "`?`" will do the `typeof var == "undefined"` as well as comparison to `null` in all cases where it's necessary - that is, where static code analysis can't tell you whether that variable has been declared.

Comment: @AaronDufour—using `typeof x == 'undefined'` doesn't tell you whether a variable has been declared or not. It only tells you that **if** it exists, it has a value of `undefined` (or not).

Comment: @RobG I'm aware of that.  `typeof x == 'undefined'` is protection from `ReferenceError`s.  `?=` is better than a bare `typeof` because it only does the extra `typeof` check when it's actually necessary.